# "right" uniformity condition for Nick's Class

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

DLOGTIME is defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLOGTIME

$\operatorname{L}$ is defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_%28complexity%29

$\operatorname{NC}$ and $\operatorname{NC}^n$ are defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29

DLOGTIME seems to be the smallest that might work.

I've read in various places that $\, \operatorname{L} \subseteq \operatorname{NC}^2 \,$, $\,$ although every place I've

found that results which states a uniformity condition uses $\operatorname{L}$-uniformity.

Is there any deterministic class $X$ such that $\, \operatorname{L} \subseteq \operatorname{NC} \,$ is known with $X$-uniform $\operatorname{NC}$, and

1. $\;$ ... $\; X\subset \operatorname{L} \;$ is known to hold?

2. $\;$ ... $\; X\subseteq \operatorname{L} \;$ is known to hold and $\, X = \operatorname{L} \,$ is not known to hold?

(1, or to a much lesser extent 2, would seem to imply that $\operatorname{L}$-uniformity is the correct condition)

Comment: Why, do we know that L is in non-uniform NC? Without that we cannot hope that it would be in some uniform NC.

Comment: Well, I've found that on page 235 of "Encyclopedia of Computer Science and Technology", and at www.cs.tau.ac.il/~zwick/circ-comp-new/three.ps . $\;$ However, the book is the only result I get when I search for the reference it points to, and the ps file does not give a proof. $\;$ I suppose I should look into that further.

Comment: $\mathsf{L} \subseteq \mathsf{NC^2} \subseteq \mathsf{NC}$

Comment: Geez, sorry, I though the question was about $NC^1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use $\mathsf{DLogTime}$ for uniformity of $\mathsf{NC}$ and $\mathsf{NC^2}$. There is no problem and the classes uniform $\mathsf{NC^k}$ remain the same and equal to $\mathsf{ATimeSpace}(O(\lg^k n),O(\lg n))$ (for $k\geq1$).

Generally, the only case that we need to be more careful is $\mathsf{NC^1}$ case where one should be careful about what needs to be in decidable in $\mathsf{DLogTime}$. If you use *extended connection language* description of circuits then everything works even in $\mathsf{NC^1}$ case.

For more on uniformity see:

Walter L. Ruzzo, "[On Uniform Circuit Complexity](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000081900386)", Journal of Computer and System Sciences, vol. 22 (1981), pp. 365–383.

Comment: Does "can use $\operatorname{DLogTime}$ for uniformity" mean "$\, \operatorname{L} \subseteq \operatorname{NC}^2 \,$ still holds"?

Comment: Yes, it means that $\mathsf{DLogTime}$ uniform $\mathsf{NC^2}$ is equal to $\mathsf{ATimeSpace}(O(\lg^2 n),O(\lg n))$ which contains $\mathsf{NL} = \mathsf{NSpace}(O(\lg n)) \supseteq \mathsf{DSpace}(O(\lg n)) = \mathsf{L}$.